# How would I change this ATM code so that it

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import userAccountInformation.csv;

public class AtmMachine {

 private double availableBalance;
 private double totalBalance;
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 public int userAccount() {
  System.out.print("Please enter your account number: ");
  int account;
  account = input.nextInt();
  validateInput();
  return account;
 }

 public int userPin() {
  System.out.print("Please enter your pin number: ");
  int pin;
  pin =input.nextInt();
  validateInput();
  return pin;
 }

public void startAtm() {
 userAccount();
 userPin();
 drawMainMenu();
}

public void drawMainMenu() {
 int selection;

 System.out.println("\nATM main menu:");
 System.out.println("1 - View account balance");
 System.out.println("2 - Withdraw funds");
 System.out.println("3 - Add funds");
 System.out.println("4 - Terminate transaction");
 System.out.print("Choice: ");
 selection =input.nextInt();

 switch(selection) {

 case 1:
 viewAccountInfo();
 break;
 case 2:
 withdraw();
 break;
 case 3:
 addFunds();
 break;
 case 4:
 System.out.println("Thank you for using this ATM!!! goodbye");
 }
}

public void viewAccountInfo() {
 System.out.println("Account Information:");
 System.out.println("\t--Total balance: $"+totalBalance);
 System.out.println("\t--Available balance: $"+availableBalance);
 drawMainMenu();
}

public void deposit(int depAmount) {
 System.out.println("\n***Please insert your money now...***");
 totalBalance =totalBalance +depAmount;
 availableBalance =availableBalance +depAmount;
}

public void checkNotSufficientFunds(int withdrawAmount) {
 if(totalBalance -withdrawAmount < 0)
 System.out.println("\n***ERROR!!! Insufficient funds in you accout***");
 else {
  totalBalance =totalBalance -withdrawAmount;
  availableBalance =availableBalance -withdrawAmount;
  System.out.println("\n***Please take your money now...***");
 }
}

public void addFunds() {

 int addSelection;

 System.out.println("Deposit funds:");
 System.out.println("1 - $20");
 System.out.println("2 - $40");
 System.out.println("3 - $60");
 System.out.println("4 - $100");
 System.out.println("5 - Back to main menu");
 System.out.print("Choice: ");
 addSelection =input.nextInt();

 switch(addSelection) {

 case 1:
 deposit(20);
 drawMainMenu();
 break;
 case 2:
 deposit(40);
 drawMainMenu();
 break;
 case 3:
 deposit(60);
 drawMainMenu();
 break;
 case 4:
 deposit(100);
 drawMainMenu();
 break;
 case 5:
 drawMainMenu();
 break;
 }
}

public void withdraw() {

 int withdrawSelection;

 System.out.println("Withdraw money:");
 System.out.println("1 - $20");
 System.out.println("2 - $40");
 System.out.println("3 - $60");
 System.out.println("4 - $100");
 System.out.println("5 - Back to main menu");
 System.out.print("Choice: ");
 withdrawSelection =input.nextInt();

 switch(withdrawSelection) {
 case 1:
 checkNotSufficientFunds(20);
 drawMainMenu();
 break;
 case 2:
 checkNotSufficientFunds(40);
 drawMainMenu();
 break;
 case 3:
 checkNotSufficientFunds(60);
 drawMainMenu();
 break;
 case 4:
 checkNotSufficientFunds(100);
 drawMainMenu();
 break;
 case 5:
 drawMainMenu();
 break;
 }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

 AtmMachine myAtm = new AtmMachine();
 myAtm.startAtm();
 }
}

validateInput() {

}
```

But could someone help me write the validateInput() method so that it:
1. Checks account number and password and verify against a text file of users. Allow three tries.

As well as help me change it so that it:

1. If multiple checks are being deposited, save the values in an array then update the text file.
2. Deposits, transfers, and withdrawals modify the text file.
3. If a user is NOT a customer of your bank, any withdrawals are charged an extra $2.00.
4. Balances are checked against the text file.

**Where I'm having problems:**Incorporating a text file into the code so I can check against it and update it when needed / Writing the validateInput() method.

I'm assuming this will need a lot of work so any help is appreciated...

Comment: ... assignment? If yes, please add the homework tag.

Comment: Is it you who posted the same code on 2 Aug 2007? :) http://javacodee.blogspot.com/2007/08/atm.html

Comment: I didn't post the code on javacodee.blogspot.com/2007/08/atm.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to read a file into Java. I prefer to use the following:

Read the file:

```
ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\readFile.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        accounts.Add(new Account(line));
    } 
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (br != null) {
    try {
      br.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

You have to decide on a format and then use a tokenizer or other parser to extract your information from the string that you have read in. I suggest you set up classes in your project (e.g. Account class - Properties: AccountNumber, Pin, Balance etc). Remember to add an Account(String) constructor and a toString() method to easily create an account from a string and convert the account to a string for storage in your text file.

To write the accounts back to your file (at the end of each transaction or when the program shuts down, your choice), do this:

BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;

```
    try {
        //Construct the BufferedWriter object
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

        //Start writing to the output stream
        for (int i=0; i<accounts.size(); i++) {
          bw.write(accounts.get(i).toString());
          bw.newLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //Close the BufferedWriter
        try {
            if (bw!= null) {
                bw.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No problem. If my answer helps (or not) please don't forget to vote on the answer.

Comment: 2 minor notes in the finally clauses. 1: There is no flush method for readers. 2: For Writers by API contract close() implies flush() (though the additional call doesn't actually hurt anything).

Comment: sorry, writing these things from memory so no intellisense. editted as you said.